# onActivityResult from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, onactivityresult, navigationcontroller, matisse

I have a problem regarding onActivityResult. First, I opened the Add New Message Fragment to select the image. When I select the image, it doesn't return the result to my current fragment. I put onActivityResult in both my MainActivity and AddMessageFragment but it doesn't call the result in my fragment. My MainActivity is used to set up the Navigation Controller. I use Matisse library for my image picker. Can someone please help me with me? Been stuck for the whole day with this issue.

MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

AddMessageFragment

```
@OnClick({R.id.addImage})
public void openGallery()
{
    permission.addOnStorageListener(new Permission.OnStorageSuccess()
    {
        @Override
        public void OnStorageSuccess()
        {
            permission.requestCamera();
        }
    });
    permission.addOnCameraListener(new Permission.OnCameraSuccess()
    {
        @Override
        public void OnCameraSuccess()
        {
            Matisse.from(getActivity())
                    .choose(MimeType.of(MimeType.JPEG, MimeType.PNG))
                    .countable(false)
                    .capture(true)
                    .captureStrategy(new CaptureStrategy(true, "com.gprop.users.fileprovider"))
                    .maxSelectable(1)
                    .restrictOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                    .thumbnailScale(0.85f)
                    .imageEngine(new Glide4Engine())
                    .originalEnable(false)
                    .forResult(99);
        }
    });
    permission.requestStorage();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 99 && resultCode == Main.RESULT_OK)
    {
            mSelected = Matisse.obtainPathResult(data);

            if(mSelected.size() > 0)
            {
                Glide.with(this).load(mSelected.get(0)).into(addImage);

                Luban.compress(new File(mSelected.get(0)), getActivity().getFilesDir())
                        .putGear(Luban.THIRD_GEAR)
                        .asObservable()
                        .subscribe(new Consumer<File>()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(File file) throws Exception
                            {
                                newfile = file;
                            }
                        }, new Consumer<Throwable>()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception
                            {
                                throwable.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No image selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Comment: Nope, already try it. My app will crashed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `Matisse.from()` on the `Activity` which you are getting from the `getActivity()` method, tit must be returning you your `MainActivity` and the `onActivityResult` will be called for the `MainActivity` where you are doing nothing and calling `super.onActivityResult()`.

**Possible Solutions:** .

1. Shift your `onActivityResult` code logic from your `AddMessageFragment` to `MainActivity`
2. Change you `Matisse` call from `Matisse.from(getActivity())` to `Matisse.from(this)`, because looking at the source code of `Matisse` it also supports Fragment context.

Using the second solution you should get your `onActivityResult` callback in the fragment and you won't need to change/shift any other code logic.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Use `AddMessageFragment.this`

Comment: Okay this is the most unpredictable thing. Thank you so much man. You really help me

Comment: No problem at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your activity onActivityResult method by below code

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(childTag);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
}
```

It will call your fragment onActivityResult after this execute.

Answer (score 0):

OnActivityResult() function works on Activity. I suggest you call this function on your activity and implement your logic inside your fragment onResume() function. In order to get data from Activity use global val.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).